# NT to unix password sync service?

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, sql-server-2008

I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + ASP.Net on Windows Server 2003 x86 to develop asp.net application with SQL Server 2008 Express.

I find sometimes my system is very slow (not very responsive) and I find almost at the same time, there is error in event log says something wrong with "NT to unix password sync service" (I find it a couple of times, system slow time frame matches this event log error, so I think may be this "NT to unix password sync service" causes system slow)?

Could anyone let me know what is "NT to unix password sync service" please? Is it Microsoft components? Does it needed in my scenario (could it cause system slow) and if not needed, how to disable it?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have the Services for UNIX installed on that system. See [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463208.aspx) for information.

If you're not using the UNIX services, you should be able to uninstall it through the control panel's Add and Remove Programs, or there's supposed to be a readme or install text file that describes the procedure.

As to whether you need it or not, I don't know what you may have installed it for to begin with. You may have wanted a telnet service or NFS? You could try stopping the service and setting it to disabled in the services panel. That should stop it from running altogether.

You might want to verify you have a working backup before playing with the configuration, just in case you're using it for something really important in the background of your configuration and forgot about it.

Comment: "You could try stopping the service and setting it to disabled in the services panel" -- what is the service name from Services of Control Panel?

Comment: "You may have wanted a telnet service or NFS" -- no, I have no such requirement. :-)